# Loading Data from Spark to HBase

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

Its just a FAQ.

Is there any inbuilt python library available in `Spark 1.6.1` that I can use to integrate with `HBase` through `pyspark`?

There are 3rd party libraries present on internet, but my organization is reluctant to use them.

Regards,
AS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spark` hasn't officially released packages for `HBase` but efforts are underway.

You can check [Spark Packages](https://spark-packages.org/) where you can find some libraries being built for `HBase`.

You can read [Spark SQL Data Sources API: Unified Data Access for the Apache Spark Platform](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/01/09/spark-sql-data-sources-api-unified-data-access-for-the-spark-platform.html) too which is very informative.